# running python program in yt project with STAMPEDE

Tags: python, yt-project

I have been working on this python program to find max_dens of my files but whenever I execute the file I get the same error. Can anyone please tell me what these errors refer to? I am using yt 3.1

> ## computes and plots the maximum density over time
>
> ```
>     import yt
>     #import LibCartesian3D
>     import matplotlib
>     matplotlib.use('Agg')
>     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>     import glob
>     import numpy as np
>     flashFolder = '/work/03858/thaque56/run_149/'
>     basename = 'super3d_' # sets the prefix of the plotfiles and checkpoint files. Usually 'super3d_' for MHD, 'relax_' for purehydro.
>     useAllPlotfiles = False # set True to use glob.glob to select plotfiles (by default uses all available files)
>     endcount = 5  # specify if useAllPlotfiles == False, gives the number of the last plotfile which is used
>
>     # ============================ constructs list of filenames if script is run on its own, otherwise supplied by allPlots.py !
>     def getfilenames(useAllPlotfiles,endcount):
>             if useAllPlotfiles == True:
>                     plotFilenames_own = glob.glob(flashFolder + basename + 'hdf5_plt_cnt_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
>                     plotFilenames_own.sort()
>             else:
>                     plotFilenames_own = []
>                     for n in range(0,endcount + 1):
>                             filename = flashFolder + basename + 'hdf5_plt_cnt_%04d' % n
>                             plotFilenames_own.append(filename)
>             return plotFilenames_own
>
>     #============================
>
>     def main(filenames):
>             print 'Executing maxDens.py'
>
>             max_dens = np.zeros(len(filenames))
>             time = np.zeros(len(filenames))
>
>             for n in range (len(filenames)):
>                     pf =yt.load(filenames[n])
>                     time[n] = pf.current_time
>                     dens_max, dens_max_location = pf.h.find_max('dens')
>                     max_dens[n] = dens_max
>
>             print time, max_dens
>             plt.plot(time,max_dens)
>             plt.xlabel('time [s]')
>             plt.ylabel('density [g/cm^3]')
>             plt.title('Maximum Density over Time')
>             plt.savefig('MaxDens.png')
>
>
>     if __name__ == "__main__":
>             plotFilenames_own = getfilenames(useAllPlotfiles,endcount)
>             main(plotFilenames_own)
> ```

I am also attaching the error for you convenience.

> ```
> >     TACC: Starting up job 6517689
> >     TACC: Setting up parallel environment for MVAPICH2+mpispawn.
> >     TACC: Starting parallel tasks...
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "maxDens.py", line 3, in <module>
> >         import yt
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/__init__.py",
> > line 121, in <module>
> >         from yt.data_objects.api import \
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/data_objects/api.py",
> > line 51, in <module>
> >         from . import construction_data_containers as __cdc
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/data_objects/construction_data_containers.py",
> > line 52, in <module>
> >         from yt.frontends.stream.api import load_uniform_grid
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/frontends/stream/api.py",
> > line 16, in <module>
> >         from .data_structures import \
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/frontends/stream/data_structures.py",
> > line 38, in <module>
> >         from yt.geometry.grid_geometry_handler import \
> >       File "/work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/yt/geometry/grid_geometry_handler.py",
> > line 38, in <module>
> >         from .grid_container import \
> >       File "yt/geometry/selection_routines.pxd", line 34, in init yt.geometry.grid_container (yt/geometry/grid_container.c:9108)
> >     ValueError: yt.geometry.selection_routines.SelectorObject has the wrong size, try recompiling
> >     [c557-601.stampede.tacc.utexas.edu:mpispawn_0][child_handler] MPI
> ```
>
> process (rank: 0, pid: 130364) exited with status 1
>
> > ```
> > TACC: MPI job exited with code: 1
> >
> > TACC: Shutdown complete. Exiting.
> > ```

Please help me resolve this. i think there is some problem with the yt versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that some of the C extensions yt uses that were generated with cython need to be recompiled. It turns out the `clean.sh` script doesn't delete those, so you'll have to clean them out like so:

```
$ cd /work/03858/thaque56/sw/yt-3.1/yt-x86_64/src/yt-hg/
$ hg --config extensions.purge= purge --all yt
$ python setup.py develop
```

Sorry for giving you bad advice about this on the yt mailing list last night! Hope this fixes things for you.